# Indexing Multi-Band images in OpenDataCube

Tags: sentinel-2, open-data-cube, indexing

I have a Sentinel2 based product with the following product definition. It has 2 bands in it

```
name: product_name
description: Product Name
metadata_type: eo3

metadata:
    product:
        name: 'product_name'

measurements:
    - name: 'name_of_band'
      aliases: [band_1, name_of_band]
      dtype: uint8
      nodata: 0
      units: '1'
    - name: 'name_of_band2'
      aliases: [band_2, name_of_band2]
      dtype: uint8
      nodata: 0
      units: '1'
```

I am trying to index a dataset in it and for COG conversion as well as metadata yaml generation, I am using the following link - https://eodatasets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#assemble-a-dataset-package

Here, I am writing the `write_measurement` line twice, like this

```
p.write_measurement("name_of_band", name_of_band_path)
p.write_measurement("name_of_band2", name_of_band2_path)
```

It throws the following error: `NotImplementedError: TODO: Multi-band images not currently implemented (have 2)`

I have seen similar kinds of product definitions with multiple bands here - https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-dataset-config/tree/main/products, but can't quite find the way to write multiple measurements to a dataset yaml for indexing.

The above code works fine for single-band images, but not for multiband. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was not supported yet, as none of our own datasets came with multiple bands. I've added it in `eodatasets>=0.23`.

An `index` param is now available for reading measurements:

```py
p.write_measurement("name_of_band", name_of_band_path, index=2)
```

Let me know if there are any issues.